# Why I get spiky graphs(loss vs Epochs) in CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

This is the code I created for a CNN but I've noticed these spikes on loss/epoch graph and I cannot explain. I tried adam optimizer but results still the same. I try to classify malignant or benignal breast tumors but my dataset is kind of small only 3390 pictures.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    """
    Created on Wed Dec 18 16:05:12 2019

    @author: Panagiotis Gkanos
    """
    import numpy as np 
    import tensorflow as tf
    from numpy.random import seed
    seed(1)

    tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(2)
    from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
    print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
    import tensorflow as tf
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

    import os
    os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND']='tensorflow'


    import keras
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D
    from keras.utils import np_utils
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
    from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
    import matplotlib as plt
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    import itertools

    keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=42)

    train_path='C:/Users/Panagiotis Gkanos/Desktop/dataset/40X/train'
    train_batches=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
    samplewise_center=True,rotation_range=180).flow_from_directory(train_path,
                                                      target_size=[224,224],
                                                      classes=['malignant','benign'],
                                                      class_mode='categorical',batch_size=80)

    test_path='C:/Users/Panagiotis Gkanos/Desktop/dataset/40X/test'
    test_batches=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
    samplewise_center=True,rotation_range=180).flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                                      target_size=[224,224],
                                                      classes=['malignant','benign'],
                                                      class_mode='categorical',batch_size=80)




    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),padding='same',input_shape=(224,224,3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(16,(3,3),padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides=2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))

    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),strides=2))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))


    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
    sgd = SGD(lr=0.01)
    model.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    history=model.fit_generator(train_batches,steps_per_epoch=20 ,validation_data=test_batches,
                    validation_steps=8 ,epochs=50)



    def plot_loss(history):
        train_loss=history.history['loss']
        val_loss=history.history['val_loss']
        x=list(range(1,len(val_loss)+1))
        plt.plot(x,val_loss,color='red',label='validation loss')
        plt.plot(x,train_loss,label='training loss')
        plt.xlabel('Epoch')
        plt.ylabel('Loss')
        plt.title('Loss vs. Epoch')
        plt.legend()

        plot_loss(history)
```

Graph Loss vs Epoch:

[image: Graph Loss vs Epoch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both SGD and Adam are stochastic optimizers, so the loss value will not necessarily decrease on every step and it is ok to have spikes in this graph as long as the loss is decreasing overall. Although i think your model might be overfitting on the training data. Try using regularizers or adding dropout after the model's last dense layer. It is not very conventional to use dropout in the middle layers of a CNN.